# When to use the static keyword before a method in a React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm use to writing methods in react like so:

```
class Someclass extends Component{
  ...
  someMethod () => ...
}
```

Latley I've seen a lot of code with static before the method name:

```
static someMethod() {...}
```

1. What's the static for in the context of a JavaScript Class?
2. And in the context of a React component?

Comment: A static method will be shared between every instance of your `Someclass` component, and it doesn't have access to `this`.

Comment: @Tholle I like your speed :D

Comment: @Tholle What are the use cases of that in react?

Comment: Where have you seen it a lot? In the context of React component it's only applicable to https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: @docHoliday I can't think of a nice example, to be honest. It's often used for `getDerivedStateFromProps` and properties like `propTypes`, but I can't think of when to use the static keyword in a React context outside of that.

Comment: @estus I've seen it used in sevral react native modules latley and I was wondering if it has some factory function use case

Comment: @docHoliday Yeah, if you e.g. give a method to a `renderItem` prop and it only relies on the `item` given to it as argument, a static method would work, since it's not dependent on `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are defined on the class´s prototype, static methods are not, they are functions on the class itself. You can call a static method without creating the instance of the class.

More information on the subject [here](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/javascript-classes-under-the-hood-6b26d2667677)